# How to view data in pgAdmin III

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-3

I can't believe they make it this hard.  I am at a loss about how to view the data in my database.

Is there an easy way to see what data is in my tables with pgAdmin III?  Alternatively, is there a program that I could use that does not suck?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Or, to retrieve all rows, just press the blue data grid.

[image]

The tooltip "View data in the selected object" is almost making it too easy.
Try the button with the funnel next to it to retrieve only a selection (for big tables).

Comment: Is there any way to make it *not* open in a new window?

Comment: @Dennis: None that I know of. If you want to refresh the already open window just press `[F5]`.

Answer (score 25):

Right click on the table and choose "View data"

[image]

For a list of alternatives, check out the Postgres wiki:
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Answer (score 4):

For **pgAdmin 4:** Servers -> your_server -> Databases -> your_database -> Schemas -> public -> Tables

[image]